# How do I set the default launch display?

Tags: java, swing

The output below indicates that no matter which of my two physical displays I launch this application from (see code further below), the default `screen` that it launches to  is `CGraphicsDevice[screen=0]`.

How can I adjust the `Window` property so that running `windows[0].getGraphicsConfiguration()` returns `CGraphicsDevice[screen=1]` instead of `CGraphicsDevice[screen=0]`?

**Output**

```
Window 0: 
apple.awt.CGraphicsConfig@692a3722[dev=CGraphicsDevice[screen=0],pixfmt=0]

Default output device: 
CGraphicsDevice[screen=0]

Connected Displays:
Display 0: CGraphicsDevice[screen=0]
Display 1: CGraphicsDevice[screen=1]
```

**GraphicsConfig.java**

```
public class GraphicsConfig {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
      f.setContentPane(new OkcView().panel1);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.pack();
      // f.setVisible(true);

      Window[] windows = Window.getWindows();
      for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Window " + i + ": \n" 
                            + windows[i].getGraphicsConfiguration() 
                            + "\n");
      }
      GraphicsConfiguration config = windows[0].getGraphicsConfiguration();
      System.out.println("Default output device: \n" 
                         + config.getDevice() 
                         + "\n");

      GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
      GraphicsDevice[] allScreens = env.getScreenDevices();
      System.out.println("Connected Displays:");

      for (int i = 0; i < allScreens.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Display " + i + ": " + allScreens[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Changing the location of the frame is easy, the problem is determine the information you need to determine which screen was used to launch your application.  Remember, your application may not have been launched by the user double clicking the Jar, it might have been from a short cut or the start menu or some other system driven event...

Comment: That's fine. If we're being honest, this is for me while I'm writing it. Sometimes I launch multiple copies one on each screen, and I want the application to pop up on the display I ran it from in the IDE.